# Dismiss Authentication popup while running selenium tests in Headless mode from Jenkins (with Linux Agents)

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

How to dismiss authentication popup while running selenium tests in headless mode through Jenkins ? My tests run in Linux docker containers in Jenkins Environment.

The application has SSO enabled hence in most cases, I don't get this popup unless I open the application in incognito mode or run  tests through Jenkins (where SSO doesn't work), in which case I just have to dismiss it (same as clicking on cancel button on the popup or pressing ESC key). Also note, entering credentials in the popup won't work (will not launch the application, instead gives error, could be due to oAuth/SSO).

I'm already aware of the following approaches, but none of them really work -

1. Passing credentials in URL - This approach won't work as it is not basic authentication.
2. AutoIT - works only in windows OS
3. Robot class (to press ESC key) won't work in headless mode.

How can I dismiss the authentication popup in headless mode ? I read about Wine tool as AutoIt alternative for Linux OS. Is that the only way to handle this scenario?

Comment: I am not sure of what kind of popup you mean here, because in ideal world you should be redirected to a webpage where you should be able to pass credentials and carry on with the test, all within the Selenium api. Not having enough information, I would only suggest looking into how this particular SSO works. Most probably your browser needs a specific cookie set, and perhaps you can achieve that goal in your test by first navigating to SSO provider login page, authenticating, and only then going to the app. You DO NOT want to use desktop automation tools for webapp testing in headless mode ;).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. 
It is an Authentication Popup. Looks like this - https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth